# how to get star ratings in google search results? What is that code?

Tags: schema, rating

Is it a schema code that will generate rating star? I want to put that schema code in my post or website for the better search result, please help me with that schema code.

Comment: For example: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Answer (score 0):

I get all solution from here: 
https://www.ianbrodie.com/get-star-ratings-google-search-results/
Thank you